# What are the differences in meaning between "We'll do" and "let's do"?

Tags: grammar

What are the differences in meaning between "we'll do" and "let's do"?

I need for more explanations between them and when we use each of them.

**We will do new job**

**Let's do shopping**

If both of them correct? Could u please explain the differences in meaning between them?

Comment: I suggest that you provide some examples where you've seen these structures.

Comment: we'll do an interview, or should we say:  Let's do an interview,
if both of them are correct. Could u please explain the differences in meaning between them?

Comment: Please edit your post including both examples.

Comment: I have done as what u said

Comment: I know in text messages and online messages that users, both native speakers and non, use the abbreviation u for "you" but this was borne out of necessity. In the days before "auto correct" or "predictive text" short words were preferred because it took less time to type, and if you say aloud "u"  its meaning is clear but on an English website, where there are no time constraints or a strict limit on characters, I really think there are no excuses for not writing **you** properly. We aren't on YouTube, or should I say "utube"?

Comment: :), ok, I will write it as " you" 
I Laugh really with your comment especially that's about Youtube.

Comment: Why did **you** delete the examples in your question? Asking:  "if both of them correct?" Makes no sense at all, without the examples.

Comment: Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of "will" in the future simple represents a definite plane. If I tell you we "will" do something, we are 100% sure that something will happen.

"Will" is also used for predictions when we are very sure. Example: the weather, Leonardo DiCaprio winning an Oscar, etc.

"Let's" is a suggestion. When something says "let's" +verb, they want you to either consent or decline. One could argue that it used more frequently when the speaker expects consent. "Let's", similar to "will" assumes to a high degree that the proposed action will happen, but unlike "will" requires some sort of yes or no from the audience.

Answer (score 1):

You use the auxiliary 'will' to talk about things that are going to happen in the future, especially that you are certain about or that are planned. For example:

We'll go to London tomorrow.

The second semester will start next week.

The phrase let's (let us) doesn't indicate that something is certain or planned to happen in the future; it may or may not happen.  You use the phrase to make a suggestion to the person(s) you are talking to to do someething along with you.j